# vim brace matching with comments having brace

Tags: c++, vim, vi, ctags

I am browsing my cpp code in vim using ctags . At some point I want to go to the starting point of a closing brace i.e. I want to see where this brace starts. So I press `% ( via shift + 5 )`. Most of the  times this works, but sometimes when my code has comments which include a brace it goes to the positions.

For example :

```
for(int i = 0;i<100;++i)
{ //point 1
  // this is a comment { // point2
  <some 1000 lines  code>

} <== press % here and it goes to point 2
```

How can i rectify this problem so that it goes to right place i.e. point 1.

Answer (score 2):

Use the matchit.vim macro (provided in macros from v6 on):

```
set nocompatible
filetype plugin on
runtime macros/matchit.vim
```

Should do the trick...